# How to cancel a composed RxJS observable

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

Folks, I have an app using RxJS to handle mouse events.  I am composing these events into more complex observable 'gestures'.  One such gesture is "shake".

The series of events I am trying to compose are:

```
mousedown  
mousemove left  
mousemove right  
mousemove left  
mousemove right  
mouseup
```

What I am finding is that

```
mousedown  
mouseup
mousemove left  
mousemove right  
mousemove left  
mousemove right
```

is also triggering the same result.

I have made [a fiddle demonstrating the issue on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKnFB).

My question in general is:  How do you express in RxJS that a obeservable, such as mouseup, should cancel and restart the composition of an observable?

As another example of the issue (from the same fiddle), the following events

```
mousedown  
mouseup
mousedown  
mouseup
mousedown  
mousemove left  
mousemove right  
mousemove left  
mousemove right
```

Result in 3 shake events.  I would like it to result in one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `takeUntil`

```
var down = $div.onAsObservable('mousedown');
var up = $div.onAsObservable('mouseup');
var move = $div.onAsObservable('mousemove');

var shake = down.flatMapLatest(function (downev) {
            var current = downev;
            return move
                .map(function (ev) {
                    var delta = ev.pageX - current.pageX;
                    current = ev;
                    return delta < 0 ? 'left' : 'right';
                 })
                .takeUntil(up)
                .toArray();
        })
        .subscribe(function (moves) {
            // see if moves is an array of left,right,...
```

Comment: Just reread this answer after 18 months, and learned something new (flatMapLatest).  I have a new question up if you wouldn't mind taking a look.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890358/recognizing-and-exact-series-of-events-in-rxjs